# Deployed default guestbook... server error?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, backtracking

I recently deployed the guestbook demo onto a Google AppEngine and I'm receiving a 500 Server Error. How do I backtrack the cause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Login to your account at http://appengine.google.com
2. Select your application from the list
3. Click on "Logs" on the sidebar on the left.

That should show you the server side logs.

Comment: It seems the error is: "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: guestbook/SignGuestbookServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0"

Any idea on what that means?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with AppEngine on Java. You can create another question for that. I'm sure you'll get an answer. :)